# Should I use tf.keras.utils.normalize to normalize my targets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normalization

Working on a machine learning model regression problem that predicts a score.

Usually, when using a scaler for normalization, for example [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), You get a reference to the scaler so later you can inverse your data back to its original values.

When using [tf.keras.utils.normalize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/normalize), which is (as far as I understand it) is an L2 normalization for the following Data:

```
    val target
0   1   10
1   2   20
2   3   30
3   4   40
4   5   50
```

You get this output:

```
    val     target
0   0.13484 0.13484
1   0.26968 0.26968
2   0.40452 0.40452
3   0.53936 0.53936
4   0.67420 0.67420
```

So I see no possible way to go back to the original series of `10,20,30,40,50`

**Q:** If I want to inverse the predicted targets back to their original scale, should I normalize the scores separately using MinMaxScalar?

Comment: You need to normalize your **input**, not the **output**. So, `target` shouldn't be normalized

Comment: At all? but then I cannot use, let's say sigmoid function on my final layer. Furthermore, I would like to range all my cores between 0 -1.

Comment: The sigmoid function is used for classification problems where it's either 0 or 1. But in regression problems, you need to deal with a continuous range of numbers.

Comment: But Sigmoid range is 0-1, can't I use it at the last layer if the scores range from 0-1?

Comment: yes you can, but I don't recommend it. because it would be difficult to reverse the effect of normalizing at the last layer as you stated in the question. I recommend not using any activation function at the last layer when you're doing a regression problem

Comment: Reversing with a `MinMaxScalar` is a breeze, just use `scaler.inverse_transform(scores)`. However, I'm interested in your opinion of not using sigmoid, or maybe the reasoning behind it.

Comment: OK, here is my opinion. sigmoid is defined for all-real values where the output is defined on [0, 1]. It's super useful with binary classification where the output is either `0` or `1`. In regression, it's really hurtful.. why? because `sigmoid(10)=0.9999`, and `sigmoid(20)=0.9999`, `sigmoid(30)=0.9999`... that's why

Comment: Glad I could help!!

Answer (score 3):

Neural network activations generally like their **inputs** to be normalized. Normalizing inputs to nodes in a network helps prevent the so-called vanishing (and exploding) gradients.

Generally, Batch Normalization is performed on the inputs, but it has its own drawbacks like slower predictions due to extra computation. Instead, you can use any other normalizing technique as you mentioned.

In your example instead of normalizing both input and target, normalize only input like mentioned below.

**Dataframe:**

```
val target
0   1   10
1   2   20
2   3   30
3   4   40
4   5   50
```

**Normalizing input:**

```
df["val"] = tf.keras.utils.normalize(df["val"].values,axis=-1, order=2 )[0]
```

**Input Normalized Dataframe:**

```
    val target
0   0.13484 10
1   0.26968 20
2   0.40452 30
3   0.53936 40
4   0.67420 50
```